# Stitching together a date range in snowflake and DBT and prioritising rows

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I have a SQL table that for each machine has a start and end time and the a state the machine was in. In the table the dates can overlap and so at any one point in time I could have more than one state. I am trying to create a continuous time series where I only select the highest priority state for any given interval. AN example extract of the current table is:

| time start | time end | state | Priority |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-03 19:22:00.000 | 2022-09-04 07:43:08.000 | Changeover | 12 |
| 2022-09-03 19:22:00.000 | 2022-09-04 00:44:19.000 | Sanitation | 10 |
| 2022-09-03 21:02:55.000 | 2022-09-04 00:44:19.000 | CIP | 7 |
| 2022-09-04 00:44:19.000 | 2022-09-04 07:23:09.000 | Unscheduled | 1 |
| 2022-09-04 00:44:19.000 | 2022-09-04 08:07:02.000 | Startup | 11 |

And I am trying to transform it so there is the minimum interval and during that interval the highest priority (lowest number) state is selected:

[image]

The table is around 11 million rows and the states can go for multiple hours at a time. I've tried a cross join but its not very performant.

My current query is:

```
with main as (
select
    machine_id,
    state,
    priority,
    start_date_time,
    end_date_time
from pseimenis.public_manufacturing.test),
-- Create an interval set
intervals as (
    select
        machine_id,
        start_date_time as date_time
    from main
    union
    select
        machine_id,
        end_date_time as date_time
    from main
),
interval_times as 
(select 
    machine_id,
    date_time as start_date_time,
    lead(date_time) over (partition by machine_id order by start_date_time) as end_date_time
from intervals
)
select it.*,
    m.state,
    m.priority
from interval_times it 
left join main m on it.machine_id = m.machine_id
and it.start_date_time >= m.start_date_time and m.end_date_time >= it.end_date_time
qualify row_number() over (partition by it.machine_id, it.start_date_time order by m.priority) = 1
order by it.start_date_time, priority
```

the explain text is

```
GlobalStats:
    partitionsTotal=8
    partitionsAssigned=8
    bytesAssigned=27251200
Operations:
1:0     ->Result  UNION_ALL(MAIN.MACHINE_ID, MAIN.MACHINE_ID), UNION_ALL(MAIN.START_DATE_TIME, MAIN.END_DATE_TIME), LEAD(UNION_ALL(MAIN.START_DATE_TIME, MAIN.END_DATE_TIME)) OVER (PARTITION BY UNION_ALL(MAIN.MACHINE_ID, MAIN.MACHINE_ID) ORDER BY UNION_ALL(MAIN.START_DATE_TIME, MAIN.END_DATE_TIME) ASC NULLS LAST), SYS_VW.STATE_4, SYS_VW.PRIORITY_2  
1:1          ->Sort  UNION_ALL(MAIN.START_DATE_TIME, MAIN.END_DATE_TIME) ASC NULLS LAST, SYS_VW.PRIORITY_2 ASC NULLS LAST  
1:2               ->Filter  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UNION_ALL(MAIN.MACHINE_ID, MAIN.MACHINE_ID), UNION_ALL(MAIN.START_DATE_TIME, MAIN.END_DATE_TIME) ORDER BY SYS_VW.PRIORITY_2 ASC NULLS LAST) = 1  
1:3                    ->WindowFunction  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UNION_ALL(MAIN.MACHINE_ID, MAIN.MACHINE_ID), UNION_ALL(MAIN.START_DATE_TIME, MAIN.END_DATE_TIME) ORDER BY SYS_VW.PRIORITY_2 ASC NULLS LAST)  
1:4                         ->LeftOuterJoin  joinKey: (UNION_ALL(MAIN.MACHINE_ID, MAIN.MACHINE_ID) = SYS_VW.MACHINE_ID_1), joinFilter: ((UNION_ALL(MAIN.START_DATE_TIME, MAIN.END_DATE_TIME)) >= SYS_VW.START_DATE_TIME_3) AND (SYS_VW.END_DATE_TIME_0 >= LEAD(UNION_ALL(MAIN.START_DATE_TIME, MAIN.END_DATE_TIME)) OVER (PARTITION BY UNION_ALL(MAIN.MACHINE_ID, MAIN.MACHINE_ID) ORDER BY UNION_ALL(MAIN.START_DATE_TIME, MAIN.END_DATE_TIME) ASC NULLS LAST))  
1:5                              ->WindowFunction  LEAD(UNION_ALL(MAIN.START_DATE_TIME, MAIN.END_DATE_TIME)) OVER (PARTITION BY UNION_ALL(MAIN.MACHINE_ID, MAIN.MACHINE_ID) ORDER BY UNION_ALL(MAIN.START_DATE_TIME, MAIN.END_DATE_TIME) ASC NULLS LAST)  
1:6                                   ->Aggregate  groupKeys: [UNION_ALL(MAIN.MACHINE_ID, MAIN.MACHINE_ID), UNION_ALL(MAIN.START_DATE_TIME, MAIN.END_DATE_TIME)]  
1:7                                        ->UnionAll  
1:8                                             ->WithReference  
1:9                                                  ->WithClause  MAIN  
1:10                                                       ->TableScan  PSEIMENIS.PUBLIC_MANUFACTURING.TEST  MACHINE_ID, STATE, STATE_ID_PRIORITY, START_DATE_TIME, END_DATE_TIME  {partitionsTotal=8, partitionsAssigned=8, bytesAssigned=27251200}
1:11                                             ->WithReference  
1:12                              ->Filter  M.MACHINE_ID IS NOT NULL  
1:13                                   ->JoinFilter  joinKey: (UNION_ALL(MAIN.MACHINE_ID, MAIN.MACHINE_ID) = SYS_VW.MACHINE_ID_1), joinFilter: ((UNION_ALL(MAIN.START_DATE_TIME, MAIN.END_DATE_TIME)) >= SYS_VW.START_DATE_TIME_3) AND (SYS_VW.END_DATE_TIME_0 >= LEAD(UNION_ALL(MAIN.START_DATE_TIME, MAIN.END_DATE_TIME)) OVER (PARTITION BY UNION_ALL(MAIN.MACHINE_ID, MAIN.MACHINE_ID) ORDER BY UNION_ALL(MAIN.START_DATE_TIME, MAIN.END_DATE_TIME) ASC NULLS LAST))  
1:14                                        ->WithReference  M
```

Comment: What happens to the record that has `state = 'Changeover'`? Did it change to a 'Startup' one?

Comment: Yes it priority was 12 and so there was no time in the above that it was at a higher priority than any of the other states

Comment: You should point out such changes into your post, you won't find many domain-knowledged (for the medical sector) people that know about this.

Comment: If you are creating your own, arbitrary timeseries (i.e. the start./end times cannot be calculated from the data by e.g. rounding to the nearest hour) then the only solution, that I'm aware of, is to cross join. If you update your question with the SQL statement and the EXPLAIN PLAN for it then someone may be able to suggest how to improve the performance

Comment: @NickW thanks for the suggestion. What s the best way to share an explain plan

Comment: Generate it in TABULAR/TEXT format (whichever you think makes it most readable) and paste it into your question as text

Comment: So what you've provided is not a valid SQL statement (I don't know what the first SELECT is doing and you've got CTEs with no WITH) and you've provided the EXPLAIN as JSON - which is the least readable of the possible format, rather than TABULAR/TEXT as suggested